How to extract elements from a Carto map?
I'm trying to build a database for galactic objects from the Star Wars universe, which would include the coordinates for objects in the galaxy. The closest thing that I could find for this information are these Carto maps (http://www.swgalaxymap.com/ & https://hbernberg.carto.com/viz/76e286d4-fbab-11e3-b014-0e73339ffa50/embed_map), which were compiled using known information from canon, legends, etc. The problem is that there is no downloadable catalog (with coordinates, at least) that I can use.
My question is the following: is there a way to extract this information from the Carto map? If so, how would I go about doing it? The challenge here is that the coordinate information only appears when clicking an object on the map. I'm not that well-versed in JavaScript, but I am fairly familiar with HTML.
Any advice would be much appreciated!
Haven't tried anything yet, as I don't know quite where to start.

Although you question is probably off-topic, one of the links you provided (the 1st one) has a resources page which states quote "My primary resource for the map". Have a look at that page.

Regarding the second link - open the website, and your browsers DevTools - specifically, the Network tab. Limit the display to only XHR. Reload the page, and see what shows up. Check the request format, and the response format.
